5000 crore spent on Anant Ambani wedding versus rise in recharge packs by Jio
Around 5000 crore INR (598 172 000 USD) spent on Anant Ambani's wedding, who is son of the richest Indian entrepreneur Mukesh Ambani. While doing a recharge today, I noted that the price has been raised of 239 INR for 28 days pack to 299 INR. Few years back, Jio provided for months free packs to masses that made them habituated with accessing internet over the smartphone. Now without corresponding rise in their income (rather falling due to heavy inflation), these people are now feeling stressed as something that has been made a part of their life and turned almost to necessity now becoming out of reach.
Now coming to the query, I seek opinion of experts if instead of spending so much on the wedding, could they avoided raising the cost of recharge packs? The family is reportedly taking credit of doing a social service as their spent money is being highlighted as passed to artists, food vendors, and so many others in the supply chain. Their journalists (media houses like CNBC owned by the Ambani family) can even justify how spending on Rihanna and Justin Bieber (even not sure about the spelling of this superstar) made a positive impact on the Indian economy and India.

"While doing a recharge today, I noted that the price has been raised of 239 INR for 28 days pack to 299 INR." Note that it is not at all clear what you are writing about here.


instead of spending so much on the wedding, could they avoided raising the cost of recharge packs

I understand the motivation for your question, but

you need to gather data on projected sales volume and interest rates in order to answer this question, after which you can perform a calculation with the present value formula. A snapshot of the required data is perhaps attainable, projections would require much more work.
your actual answerable question is out of sync with your motivation. The question is about financial feasibality, but you imply there is something unfair about rich people's lavish spending if they are profiting off of the poor. I too find this distasteful, but it is besides the point of your actual question. It seems like an answer along the lines of "yes, they could have avodied doing so if the interest rate remains above 4.4%" would not satisfy visitors of this question.

